# Sum from two tables and compare with a value from third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to do something which I believe is very simple, but can't figure it out in SQL Statement.
The tables

1. Invoices (column - GrossAmount)
2. Receipts (column - ReceiptValue, there could be a receipt or no receipt at all)
3. Credit notes (column - GrossCredit, there could be a credit note or none)

I want to show the total outstanding invoices, i.e., show all invoices where `Invoices.GrossAmount > (sum(Receipt.ReceiptValue) + sum(CreditNotes.GrossCredit))`.

Query needs to show all the invoices which are not fully paid or not paid at all.

InvoiceId is same in all tables as foreign key.

Using MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum each table individually (grouped by invoice) and then [left] join the results:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceId
FROM   invoices i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   InvoiceId, SUM(ReceiptValue) AS sum_receipt
           FROM     receipts
           GROUP BY InvoiceId) r ON i.InvoiceId = r.InvoiceId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   InvoiceId, SUM(GrossCredit) AS sum_credit
           FROM     credit
           GROUP BY InvoiceId) g ON i.InvoiceId = g.InvoiceId
WHERE     i.GrossAmount > COALESCE(sum_receipt, 0) + COALESCE(sum_credit, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select i.*,
       coalesce(r.sumrv, 0) as receiptValue,
       coalesce(c.sumgc, 0) as grossCredits
from invoices i left join
     (select invoiceId, sum(receiptvalue) as sumrv
      from receipts
      group by invoiceId
     ) r
     on i.invoiceId = r.invoiceId left join
     (select invoiceId, sum(grosscredit) as sumgc
      from credits c
      group by invoiceId
     ) c
     on i.invoiceId = c.invoiceId 
where i.GrossAmount > coalesce(r.sumrv, 0) + coalesce(c.sumgc, 0);
```

Three important things:

- Use `left join` so you don't drop invoices with no matching records in one or both of the tables.
- Use `coalesce()` so `NULL` values are treated as `0`.
- Do the aggregations *before* joining the tables.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff!